# Output filtering in shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

in my script file

```
for file in *.TXT
do
    echo "put $file"
    less $file | grep BPR | awk -F'CACH' {'print $1'}
done
```

i am running this command less XYZ.TXT | grep BPR | awk -F'CACH' {'print $1'}, and i get out put like this.

```
BPRC000000000008801
BPRC000000000006671
BPRP000000000005088
BPRC000000000004542
BPRP000000000003805
BPRC000000000013624
BPRC000000000235668
```

From these out put i need to calculate amount from each line and total amount as out put.

for example

```
BPRC000000000008801         88.01
BPRC000000000006671         66.71
BPRP000000000005088         50.88
BPRC000000000004542         45.42
BPRP000000000003805         38.05
BPRC000000000013624         136.24
BPRC000000000235668         2356.68
```

and final out put should be the total amount. How can i do this. please help me.

Comment: So given a `BPRC0....000NNNNMMMM` you need a column with `NNNNMM.MM`?

Comment: yea. and i need the total amount as well by adding all NNNNMM.MM values

Comment: Not a solution really, but a command like this: `less XYZ.TXT | grep BPR | awk -F'CACH' {'print $1'}` can be much more simply written: `awk -F'CACH' '/BPR/ {print $1}' XYZ.TXT`.

Answer (score 1):

Try with two `sub()` functions. The first one to remove all characters until a non-zero number. And the second one to add the decimal point:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { OFS = "\t" } 
    { $2 = $1; 
      sub( /^[^0]*0*/, "", $2 ); 
      sub( /..$/, ".\&", $2 ); 
      print $0 
    }
' data
```

It yields:

```
BPRC000000000008801     88.01
BPRC000000000006671     66.71
BPRP000000000005088     50.88
BPRC000000000004542     45.42
BPRP000000000003805     38.05
BPRC000000000013624     136.24
BPRC000000000235668     2356.68
```

Comment: As you just need to divide /100 the number and the leading zeros don't bother, this can also make it: `gsub(/[A-Z]/,"", $0); print $0/100`

Comment: @fedorqui: Yes. Thank you. Based in your idea perhaps would have been faster to do `$2 = $2 / 100` instead of the second `sub()`. I looked at it only as strings and not numbers. But, hey! I will leave like these so other answers used it already and this is another approach, although not the best one, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
awk -F'[A-Z]+' '{total += $2/100} END {printf "%.2f", total}' data
```

Input data:

```
BPRC000000000008801
BPRC000000000006671
BPRP000000000005088
BPRC000000000004542
BPRP000000000003805
BPRC000000000013624
BPRC000000000235668
```

Output:

```
2781.99
```

If you want output at every step:

```
awk -F'[A-Z]+' '{printf "%s\t%.2f\n",$0, $2/100; total += $2/100} END {printf "Total = %.2f\n", total}' data
```

Output:

```
BPRC000000000008801     88.01
BPRC000000000006671     66.71
BPRP000000000005088     50.88
BPRC000000000004542     45.42
BPRP000000000003805     38.05
BPRC000000000013624     136.24
BPRC000000000235668     2356.68
Total = 2781.99
```

Comment: I have tried this. but i am getting value like 2.88315e+06. i have more than 100 lines of BPR entries. :(

Comment: @Ricky check my edit. you need formatted output. Use `printf "%.2f", total` instead of just `print total`. check also step by step output in second command.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
awk -F'CACH' {'print $1'}
```

say

```
awk -F'CACH' '{c=$1;sub(/[^0-9]*/,"",c);}{print $1, c/100}'
```

---

EDIT: In order to get the total, say

```
awk -F'CACH' '{c=$1;sub(/[^0-9]*/,"",c);total+=c/100}{print $1, c/100}END{printf "%.2f", total}'
```

Comment: Brother this is working for me. but i need to calculate total amount as well.